# Proving that Every Quadratic Form With Only Cross Product Terms is Indefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I've looked into this statement for a while (in fact, maybe for *too* long), and I thought to myself that I had to prove it

> If $Q \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a quadratic form with *only* cross product terms, then $Q$ is *indefinite.*

I've been *really* scratching my head over this one. I constructed a general symmetric matrix that corresponds to this quadratic form. $$A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & \frac{a_1}{2} & \frac{a_3}{2} \\\ \frac{a_1}{2} & 0 & \frac{a_2}{2} \\\ \frac{a_3}{2} & \frac{a_2}{2} & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Then I computed the characteristic polynomial to get $$\operatorname{char}_A(\lambda) = -\lambda^3\Biggl(\lambda + \frac{\sqrt{a_1^2 + a^2_2 + a^2_3}}{2}\Biggr)\Biggl(\lambda - \frac{\sqrt{a_1^2 + a^2_2 + a^2_3}}{2}\Biggr) + \frac{a_1a_2a_3}{4}$$

The last constant term is causing a *lot* of issues for me. If one of the entries is 0, then  we're left with a good polynomial and we clearly see that the eigenvalues of $A$ alternate. We've proved the statement!..almost :(

If all of the coefficients are nonzero, then this seems impossible to factor into a product of linear factors. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: What does "only cross product terms" mean?

Comment: $Q(-1,1,0)=-Q(1,1,0).$

Comment: As in, in the form of $a_1x_1x_2 + a_2x_1x_3 + a_3x_2x_3$. You don't have "pure" squares at all.

Comment: @AnneBauval I'm sorry but I don't know what that is supposed to entail 

Comment: A quadratic form that takes on negative and positive values given different inputs.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Can't believe I missed that! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to prove that a matrix $Q$ is indefinite is to exhibit vectors $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ such that $\mathbf x^{\mathsf T} Q \mathbf x > 0$ and $\mathbf y^{\mathsf T}Q \mathbf y < 0$. This is a much less constrained search than searching for eigenvectors or eigenvalues of $Q$.

(In general, another good approach is [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), but here it's inconclusive because the first principal minor is $0$.)

In the case of a matrix with only off-diagonal terms, we do not have to look far. In fact, the full power of that condition is not necessary: it's enough to have indices $i$ and $j$ such that $Q_{ii} = Q_{jj} = 0$ while $Q_{ij} = Q_{ji} \ne 0$. When $i=1$ and $j=2$, we have $$Q = \begin{bmatrix}0 & a & * \\ a & 0 & * \\ * & * & *\end{bmatrix}$$ where $*$ means "I don't care". Let $\mathbf x = (1,1,0)$ and $\mathbf y = (1,-1,0)$. Then
$$
   \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & a & * \\ a & 0 & * \\ * & * & *\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = 2a
$$
while
$$
   \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & a & * \\ a & 0 & * \\ * & * & *\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = -2a.
$$
We do not know if $a$ is positive or negative, but either way, $\mathbf x^{\mathsf T} Q \mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y^{\mathsf T}Q \mathbf y$ have opposite signs: one is positive and one is negative. This proves that $Q$ is indefinite.

Answer (score 2):

The following details my first comment. Assume $Q\ne0.$ Wlog, $a_1>0.$ Then, $Q(1,1,0)>0$ and $Q(-1,1,0)<0,$ hence $Q$ is indefinite.

Answer (score 2):

For the quadratic form $Q(x,y,z) = axy + bxz + cyz$, its associated symmetric bilinear form is
$$
B((x,y,z),(x',y',z')) = \frac{1}{2}a(xy' + x'y) + \frac{1}{2}b(xz' + x'z) + \frac{1}{2}c(yz' + y'z).
$$
The roles of the $x, y$, and $z$ are symmetric, so without loss of generality $a \not= 0$. An orthogonal basis of $\mathbf R^3$ for this bilinear form is $\{\mathbf v,\mathbf w,\mathbf u\}$, where $\mathbf v = (1,a,0)$ with $Q(\mathbf v) = a^2$, $\mathbf w = (1,-a,0)$ with $Q(\mathbf w) = -a^2$, and $\mathbf u = (c,b,-a)$ with $Q(\mathbf u) = -abc$. Since these vectors are orthogonal,
$$
Q(x\mathbf v + y\mathbf w + z\mathbf w) = x^2Q(\mathbf v) + y^2Q(\mathbf w) + z^2Q(\mathbf u) = a^2x^2 - a^2y^2 - abcz^2.
$$
So that exhibits a diagonalization of $Q$ (a basis of $\mathbf R^3$ in which $Q$ attains a diagonal form (no cross terms). Making the change of variables $x \mapsto x/a$, $y \mapsto y/a$, and $z \mapsto z/a$ changes $Q$ into $x^2 - y^2 - (bc/a^2)z^2$.